# How do I set the value of a dependency poperty of a UIControl that has been cast to a Framework Element?

Tags: c#, wpf, binary-tree, quantitative-finance

I want to build a UI control for a binary tree - like the ones used in [Stochastic Calculus for Finance I: The Binomial Asset Pricing Model](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-Binomial-Textbooks/dp/0387249680.)

My current implementation has the nodes drawing as I'd like. This is using a custom UI element (that is currently just an ellipse [node] and a line [edge] ) being passed into an ItemsControl. I have implemented the `MeasureOverride()` and `ArrangeOverride()` methods in the control that contains this `ItemsControl` to achieve this layout. My plan, that doesn't work, is to set the destination of the line to be the parent element of the node at the end of the `ArrangeOverride()` method once the nodes are all in place. I am unable to downcast the children of the `ItemsControl` to the custom UI Element and so I cannot directly modify the `ParentCoordinate` member.

So I am trying to access this property using the `GetValue()` function and this seems to work. Even the `SetValue()` function seems to work. However, this seems to have no effect on the UI. I am unsure whether it is an issue with me setting the value or updating the UI appropriately, once the value is set (or both!).

Any help would be greatly appreciated - furthermore, any other suggestions on implementation of my project is welcome.

[What I have vs What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHOHV.png)

[Github Repo for ref](https://github.com/JoesUsername98/Delta)

The below details how I am trying to set the destination of the line.

```
    protected virtual Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (ContentPresenter child in Children)
        {
           // Arrange UI Elements
        }

        foreach (ContentPresenter child in Children)
        {
            var parentNode = child.Content as INode<State>;
            var UIParent = child as FrameworkElement;

            foreach (ContentPresenter otherChild in Children)
            {
                var otherNodeChild = otherChild.Content as INode<State>;
                if (otherNodeChild.Previous != parentNode)
                    continue;

                var uiOtherChild = otherChild as FrameworkElement;
                var originalPos = uiOtherChild.GetValue(UINode.ParentCoordinateProperty); // Check current value for debugging
                var parentCoords =  UIParent.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)); // Get correct value for the line to be drawn to
                otherChild.SetCurrentValue( UINode.ParentCoordinateProperty , parentCoords); // set the value
                var changedPos = uiOtherChild.GetValue(UINode.ParentCoordinateProperty); // verify in debug that the value has been updated
            }
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
```

The next code snippet shows how I am trying to set the destination of the line in the XAML.

```
<Line Stroke='Black'
          StrokeThickness='3'
          X1='{Binding centre}'
          Y1='{Binding centre}'
          X2='{Binding Path=DataContext.ParentCoordinate.X ,Mode=TwoWay}'
          Y2='{Binding Path=DataContext.ParentCoordinate.Y ,Mode=TwoWay}' />
```

And finally the way I have set up my dependency property in the element

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    // Where the Child-To-Parent line connects to 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentCoordinateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ParentCoordinate",  
                                    typeof(System.Windows.Point), 
                                    typeof(UINode), 
                                    new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnParentCoordinatePropertyChangedCallBack))); 

    public System.Windows.Point ParentCoordinate
    {
        get { return (System.Windows.Point)GetValue(ParentCoordinateProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(ParentCoordinateProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    private static void OnParentCoordinatePropertyChangedCallBack(DependencyObject d,
                              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UINode UserControl1Control = d as UINode;

        if (UserControl1Control != null)
            UserControl1Control.OnParentCoordinateChanged(e);   
    }

    protected virtual void OnParentCoordinateChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("ParentCoordinate");
    }
```

Comment: From your description it appears wrong what you are doing. The layout of the items of an ItemsControl is done by its ItemsPanel, which by default is a StackPanel, but could be any other Panel, e.g. a Canvas or a custom Panel. The ContentPresenters that are the default item containers of an ItemsControl will then become the direct child element of the ItemsPanel.

Comment: You could also create a custom ItemsControl that creates custom item container elements by overriding the [GetContainerForItemOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) method.

Comment: @Clemens, looks like this might just work. I'll try to find time this week after work to implement this and post my results here. Thanks for the help!